# How do I insert a UNIX timestamp into oracle database using PHP

Tags: php, sql, database, oracle, timestamp

I've looked around stack overflow (there are a lot of these questions, but none with PHP).

I have a table which is:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
    my_id                   number(8)
                            NOT NULL
                            PRIMARY KEY,

    creation_date           timestamp
                            NOT NULL
);
```

I am trying to insert the current time into the table. I want to insert it by using a value (not sql short cuts like `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. For example using the `time()` function in php.

```
$customID = 1;
$currTime = time();

$sql = "INSERT INTO test (my_id, creation_date) 
        VALUES (:my_id, :creation_date)";
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":my_id", $customID);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":creation_date", $currTime);
oci_execute($stid);
```

However, when I run the above statement, I am getting the error:

`Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00904: "CREATION_DATE": invalid identifier`

Comment: Be careful with oracle `timestamp` data type.  It's not a proper timestamp (by which I mean it doesn't represent an instant properly), it's just a more accurate date-time.  By this I mean that it stores the date and time _in the current timezone_ of the connection but without timezone data.  If you always only set it externally, using a fixed date then it works.  But if you ever use current_timestamp it doesn't (try inserting a row using current_timestamp then changing time zone and inserting another).

Comment: If you use it you need to ensure all timestamps are saved as UTC. Otherwise use `timestamp with time zone`.  I guess you could say the problem is with `current_timestamp` but whichever it's a risk

Answer (score 0):

UNIX timestamp is in epoch format which is just numbers, but you are using timestamp format to store the Unix time. Instead, change the data type to integer it will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use such a conversion below

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO test (my_id, creation_date) 
        VALUES (:my_id, date'1970-01-01' + (:creation_date / 60 / 60 / 24 ) )";
```

*Since, this count starts at the Unix Epoch on January 1st, 1970 at UTC. And the rest is obviously related with the fractions for hour, minute and second in every single day.*

Comment: Can you explain the syntax of this?

Comment: @Ross you most probably have a value about 1553990400. That's calculated by the number of seconds since the date January 1st, 1970. e.g. You need to add 60 * 60* 24 = 86400 seconds for each day to this date. As a result this is the reverse operation for that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a less known function in oracle called numtodsinterval(value, 'intervalunit') that can be used. Like this.

```
select to_date('19700101','YYYYMMDD') + numtodsinterval(1553990400,'SECOND') from dual;
```

Or like this in your context (not tested)

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO test (my_id, creation_date) 
        VALUES (:my_id, to_date('19700101','YYYYMMDD') + numtodsinterval(:creation_date ,'SECOND'))";
```

[Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions103.htm)

Comment: Your second example has a mismatch in the date formats in `to_date('1970-01-01','YYYYMMDD')`